# Google Looker Studio, calculation issues/control panel

Tags: sum, looker-studio, calculation, dimension, controlpanel

I have an calculation issue with Google Looker studio.

I have a table in one of the report like this

```
Test       Three Months           Year
Column1      12,000,000     48,000,000
Column2      13,000,000     52,000,000
Column3      14,000,000     56,000,000
Sum          39,000,000    156,000,000
```

The `Year` is a calculation, added in the `ADD A FIELD`. As soon as I remove the `Test` from `Dimension`, the expected Output would be the same as the Sum, so

```
Three Months              Year
  39,000,000       156,000,000
```

However the result I get is as following, where the number has being doubled.

```
Three Months              Year
  39,000,000        78,000,000
```

Another strange thing, when I single out Column1 then I get the desired Output so,

```
Three Months              Year
  12,000,000        48,000,000
```

But as soon as I add Column2 then it doubles the number, rather than divide `Three Months` by 3 times 12.

The data has 117k rows and has the size of 11mb.

Hope this makes sense.